How to cast a spark dataframe's nullable columns into non-nullable without using the rdd api?
I have a pyspark dataframe with a nullable column that I want to transform into another dataframe and have the column be non-nullable:
from pyspark.sql.types import (
    StringType,
    StructType,
    StructField,
)

s = StructType(
    [
        StructField("ColumnA", StringType(), True)
    ]
)

df = spark.createDataFrame([("Blah")], schema=s)

df.printSchema()  # nullable

df2 = df.select(df.ColumnA)

df2.printSchema()  # still nullable (but want to be non-nullable)

I've tried:

adding an IS NOT NULL filter to prompt the schema inference
casting as StringType()
setting df2.schema['ColumnA'].nullabe = False

but nothing works.
I can't use the rdd API unfortunately.
For context, the larger problem is that I want to:

take a Databricks delta table with nullable columns
transform it into another delta table with equivalent but non-nullable columns


I think you can use a list comprehension:
new_fields = []
for field in df.schema:
    if field.nullable:
        field.nullable = False
    new_fields.append(field)  
s2 = StructType(new_fields)

Then when you create df2, all fields are non-nullable:
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([("test1", "test2")], schema=s2)
df2.printSchema()

root
 |-- ColumnA: string (nullable = false)
 |-- ColumnB: string (nullable = false)


I need to create df2 by querying against df though.
